# Select data from the most recent row, with a particular ID

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a database which looks like this:

```
ID   |   account_ID   |       date_time       |   followers
--------------------------------------------------------------
1    |         1813   |  2014-11-16 09:31:52  |        1527
--------------------------------------------------------------
2    |         1826   |  2014-11-16 09:31:52  |         900
--------------------------------------------------------------
3    |         1854   |  2014-11-16 09:32:25  |       15342
--------------------------------------------------------------
4    |         1813   |  2014-11-16 16:31:52  |        1539
--------------------------------------------------------------
5    |         1826   |  2014-11-16 16:31:52  |         905
--------------------------------------------------------------
6    |         1854   |  2014-11-16 15:32:25  |       15349
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

The database repeats the same sort of entries twice-daily. So each day there will be two new entries for `account_ID` 1813, 1826, 1854 etc.

How can I select the number of `followers` for the last entry for a particular `account_ID`?

So using the data above, I would include the `account_ID 1813` and get the `follower_count` 1539.

I'm using PHP and mySQLi if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select followers
from your_table
where account_ID = 1813
order by date_time desc
limit 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this Query

```
  select account_Id, follower_count from TAble where date_time =
 (select max(date_time) from table where account_ID = 1813)
```

Query itself Explains :

- First get max Date of that Account Id
- Select the Follower Count of that Id on max date..

Answer (score 1):

May be below query help you

```
select followers
from your_table
where account_ID = 1813
order by date_time desc
limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The main select give your distinct values of accounts ... You can give there a where clausule and concretely account_id. Clausule Cross apply give you clamped select used in row per row by where clausule in.some explain : Main select value is 1, then clamped select use it in where clausule and returns last inserted followers , because there is order by clausule

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.account_id ,z.followers
FROM YourTable a
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 followers FROM YourTable x WHERE a.account_id = x.account_id order by ID DESC) z
```

Comment: Please add some explanation for the OP.

Comment: The main select give your distinct values of accounts ... You can give there a where clausule and concretely account_id. Clausule Cross apply give you clamped select used in row per row by where clausule in.some explain : Main select value is 1, then clamped select use it in where clausule and returns last inserted followers , because there is order by clausule...